# RAP War not being deployed correctly

Tags: java, tomcat, war, eclipse-rap

everyone. I am writing my first RAP application. It's running flawlessly on my IDE environment using jetty.
Nevertheless, when I try to generate a war product configuration and export this application the following Log shows up on my **Apache TomCat 9.0**:

```
 !SESSION 2017-01-07 11:11:27.174 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=unknown
    java.version=1.8.0_112
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -registryMultiLanguage
    Command-line arguments:  -registryMultiLanguage

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.174
    !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
    !STACK 0
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet [17]
      Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.179
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge [18]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet; version="1.0.0"
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet"; bundle-version="1.3.0.v20160517-1559"; version="1.2.0"
       org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet [17]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.jface 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.184
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.rap.jface [23]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"
       org.eclipse.rap.rwt [25]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.jface.databinding 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.188
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.rap.jface.databinding [24]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160425-0854"
       org.eclipse.rap.jface [23]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"
              org.eclipse.rap.rwt [25]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.rwt 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.191
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.rap.rwt [25]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.195
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi [26]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.5.0,3.2.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.ui 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.198
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.rap.ui [27]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"
       org.eclipse.rap.rwt [25]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.1.0.20151219-0931"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench [28]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160425-0854"
              org.eclipse.rap.jface [23]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi; version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi"; bundle-version="3.1.0.20150813-1927"; version="3.1.0"
              org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi [26]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.5.0,3.2.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160425-0854"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.201
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench [28]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.jface; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160425-0854"
       org.eclipse.rap.jface [23]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"
              org.eclipse.rap.rwt [25]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.3.0,4.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.rap.rwt; bundle-version="3.1.0.20160527-1719"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi; version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi"; bundle-version="3.1.0.20150813-1927"; version="3.1.0"
       org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi [26]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.servlet; version="[2.5.0,3.2.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.205
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.3.0.v20160517-1559.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.208
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge_1.0.300.v20130327-1442.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.212
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rap.jface_3.1.0.20160425-0854.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.215
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rap.jface.databinding_3.1.0.20160401-1253.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.218
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rap.rwt_3.1.0.20160527-1719.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.222
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi_3.1.0.20150813-1927.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.225
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rap.ui_3.1.0.20150624-1329.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-01-07 11:11:27.228
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench_3.1.0.20151219-0931.jar was not resolved.
```

Here is my Application Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Catalogo
Bundle-SymbolicName: catalogo;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: catalogo.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.rap.ui,
 ksoap;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 json;bundle-version="20160810.0.0"
Import-Package: javax.servlet
Export-Package: catalogo
```

and my plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="mailapp.entrypoints"
         point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
      <entrypoint
            path="/mail"
            applicationId="catalogo.mailapp"
            id="mailapp.entrypoint">
      </entrypoint>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="catalogo.mailapp"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            thread="main"
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            visible="true">
         <run
               class="catalogo.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="RAP Perspective"
            class="catalogo.Perspective"
            id="catalogo.perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            allowMultiple="true"
            class="catalogo.View"
            icon="icons/Logo-FS - Copy.jpg"
            id="catalogo.view"
            name="Tela Inicial"
            restorable="false">
      </view>
      <view
            allowMultiple="false"
            class="catalogo.MyView"
            icon="icons/Logo-FS - Copy.jpg"
            id="catalogo.MyView"
            name="Tabela">
      </view>
      <view
            allowMultiple="true"
            class="catalogo.TelaPedidos"
            icon="icons/Logo-FS - Copy.jpg"
            id="catalogo.TelaPedidos"
            name="Tela Pedidos"
            restorable="false">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="Mail"
            id="catalogo.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Open Mailbox"
            description="Opens a mailbox"
            categoryId="catalogo.category"
            id="catalogo.open">
      </command>
      <command
            name="Open Message Dialog"
            description="Opens a message dialog"
            categoryId="catalogo.category"
            id="catalogo.openMessage">
      </command>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

also, here is the launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.rap.ui.launch.RAPLauncher">
<booleanAttribute key="append.args" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="askclear" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="automaticAdd" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="automaticValidate" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="bootstrap" value=""/>
<stringAttribute key="checked" value="[NONE]"/>
<booleanAttribute key="clearConfig" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="clearws" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="configLocation" value="${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/catalogo"/>
<booleanAttribute key="default" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="default_auto_start" value="true"/>
<intAttribute key="default_start_level" value="4"/>
<booleanAttribute key="includeOptional" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.appendEnvironmentVariables" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -console -consolelog"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.SOURCE_PATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.pde.ui.workbenchClasspathProvider"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.log.stderr.threshold=info"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.browserMode" value="EXTERNAL"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.contextpath" value="/"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.dataLocation" value="${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rap.tools.launch/catalogo"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.developmentMode" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.openBrowser" value="true"/>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.port" value="1234"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.servletPath" value="/mail"/>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.sessionTimeout" value="0"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.terminatePrevious" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.useDefaultDataLocation" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.useManualContextPath" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.useManualPort" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.rap.launch.useSessionTimeout" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="pde.version" value="3.3"/>
<booleanAttribute key="show_selected_only" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="target_bundles" value="com.ibm.icu.base@default:default,javax.servlet@default:default,javax.xml@default:default,json@default:default,ksoap@default:default,org.apache.felix.gogo.command@default:default,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime@default:default,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell@default:default,org.eclipse.core.commands@default:default,org.eclipse.core.contenttype@default:default,org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans@default:default,org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable@default:default,org.eclipse.core.databinding.property@default:default,org.eclipse.core.databinding@default:default,org.eclipse.core.expressions@default:default,org.eclipse.core.jobs@default:default,org.eclipse.core.runtime@default:true,org.eclipse.equinox.app@default:default,org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:true,org.eclipse.equinox.console@default:default,org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty@default:default,org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry@default:default,org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet@default:default,org.eclipse.equinox.preferences@default:default,org.eclipse.equinox.registry@default:default,org.eclipse.help@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.continuation@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.http@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.io@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.security@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.server@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet@default:default,org.eclipse.jetty.util@default:default,org.eclipse.osgi.services@default:default,org.eclipse.osgi@-1:true,org.eclipse.rap.design.example@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.jface.databinding@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.jface@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.rwt@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.ui.forms@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.ui.views@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench@default:default,org.eclipse.rap.ui@default:default"/>
<booleanAttribute key="tracing" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="useCustomFeatures" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="useDefaultConfigArea" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="workspace_bundles" value="catalogo*1.0.0.qualifier@default:default"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Does anyone knows what is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check that your server environment has all those dependencies (Equinox HTTP Servlet 1.3.0 or higher) installed?

Comment: yes it does. What seems to be missing is the Javax.Servlet jar. On this log, it says that Javax.servlet 2.3.0 and 2.5.0 are required. Should I copy both to the server deployment folder?

Comment: Just to update the topic. I have changed the Deployment Server version (Now I am using apache tomcat 8.5 and it worked just fine) same war, same stuff, just a different server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first things first i would look into the server binary folder and see which class files were generated as a result of unpacking your war. that will tell you if the war translates your dependencies. i found it easier to just copy the project folder out from my IDE into to webapps folder, deploy, and then add the built class files to the server's deployment folder.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if this has helped you. I Saw that you as well are a newer user and would like to pass on information (and I really would like to provide useful comments to other posts!). Please read up on what should be "accepted as answer".